# Marionette Collection View, fetching collection doesn't trigger events

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, view, collections, marionette

I have got a problem: My `CollectionView` doesn't render my `ItemViews`. I pass a collection from a Layout to a collection view. I am fetching the collection in the `CollectionView`:

In the Layout:

```
    // Create a a collection for the view
    this.articles = new Articles(null, {
        organizationId : this.model.organizationId,
        projectId : this.model.id
    });

    var articlesView = new ArticleCollectionView({ collection : this.articles});
    this.articlesRegion.show(articlesView);
```

In the CollectionView:

```
define([
    'marionette',
    'templates',
    'i18n!nls/projectDashboard',
    'views/projectDashboard/ArticleItem'
], function (Marionette, templates, msg, ArticleItemView) {

    return Marionette.CollectionView.extend({

        initialize : function () {
            this.listenTo(this.collection, "reset", this.render);
            this.collection.fetch();
        },

        itemView : ArticleItemView

    });

});
```

In the ItemView:

```
define([
    'marionette',
    'templates',
    'models/Article'
],
function (Marionette, templates, Article) {

    return Marionette.ItemView.extend({

        initialize : function () {
            console.log('itemviewrender');
        },

        template : templates.projectDashboard.articleItem
    });

});
```

The setup in general is working. I found one way to get this working: Fetch the collection in the layout and show the `CollectionView` in the region on the success callback.

But adding listeners on the collectionView for the collection fails. No event is fired for imperative and declarative listeners like

```
this.collection.on('reset', this.render, this);
```

or

```
collectionEvents : {
  'reset' : 'render'
}
```

I simply want to rerender the collection View with it's item Views if the collection is fetched. I am sure i missed something. Any help is appreciated!

UPDATE: I found something interesting:
I already said if I fetch the collection in the layout and create the collectionView on the success callback it works. The interesting is: The listeners do work too if I pass the fetched collection. I trigger them by calling `this.collection.fetch()` in `initialize` again. Then the rerendering works. It must be something around the collection pass from the layout.

Comment: where are binding the event ? shouldn't it be in the `CollectionView` initialize method? Also try using `listenTo` instead of `on`

Comment: they are in the collectionView, i should add one in the CollectionView for better understanding i guess, doenst work with listenTo either

Comment: this is interesting. according to docs it seems you don't need to manually bind events as Marionnette does it automatically for you, see: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md#collectionview-render . In that case it seems to a weird issue,

Comment: can you put a breakpoint in your app at line#1202 here > https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/lib/backbone.marionette.js and see if it gets called correctly.

Comment: It is called correctly

Comment: maybe it is something about the layout, i read : https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.layout.md#re-rendering-a-layout and it is kind of confusing, but maybe describes the weird behaviour

Comment: Which version of Marionette do you use? Links to docs and github's source code pointing to the latest version. But you using `itemview` property in `CollectionView` declaration which has been changed to `childView` in version 2.x of Marionette.

Comment: unfortunately i am not working on this anymore, i currently dont have time to take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the collectionEvents

Here is an example from the Marionette Docs

```
 Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
   collectionEvents: {
    "sync": "render"
   }
 });
```

In the example the render will be triggered when the collection has been fully populated from your back-end

[modelEvents and collectionEvents](http://marionettejs.com/docs/marionette.compositeview.html#modelevents-and-collectionevents)